# Spacing issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
puts 'Hello, what\'s your first name?'
firstName = gets.chomp
puts 'What is your middle name?'
middleName = gets.chomp
puts 'Finally, what is your last name?'
lastName = gets.chomp
puts 'Nice to meet you ' + firstName + middleName + lastName + '. :)'
```

I want there to be a space between the first name and middle name, and another space between the middle name and the last name.  How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by space out?

Comment: `puts 'Nice to meet you ' + ' '+ firstName + ' ' + middleName + ' ' +  lastName + '. :)'`

Comment: There are no spaces because you didn't put any there... This is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
puts 'Nice to meet you ' + firstName + ' ' + middleName + ' ' + lastName + '. :)'
```

Comment: Thanks! Next time I'll  remember this. Thank you Elyasin.

Answer (score 5):

I advise to use string interpolation instead of concatenation:

```
puts "Nice to meet you #{firstName} #{middleName} #{lastName}. :)"
```

It is much easier to read and to understand. Note that you have to use double quotes (`"`) to make this work.